# Normally open pushbutton that remains closed until fully released

Tags: components, button, component-selection, mechanical

### Description of desired item

I'm looking for a button component that is normally open, stays open while pushing it, closes when the maximum travel distance is reached, **and then stays closed until fully released again**. Optimally, the travel distance is adjustable.

```
|===]  open     initial state
|==]   open     pushing 
|=]    open     pushing
|]     closed   maximum travel
|=]    closed   releasing
|==]   closed   releasing
|===]  open     fully released
```

### My thoughts so far

I've considered using a sliding potentiometer with a spring and check the push/release state digitally. However, I'd like to keep this simple and digital involvement to a minimum. A "pure" hardware based approach is much preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation for such a component? If so, that's off-topic. Or are you looking to design one yourself?

Comment: For pure hardware you might be better on a mechanical hardware site rather than electronics. However, there are plenty of ways you can embody 'lost motion' into a link that operates a switch that's stable in both positions, like a conventional toggle or rotary switch. I can think of a big ugly way to do it, I guess the trick would be to make something small and neat. How much space have you got, above the panel, below the panel?

Comment: What are your distances? min and max travel to switch operate, min and max over-travel available, min and max distances to switch release, min and max over-travel to rest state (only eight parameters!)?

Comment: I say give up on having it your way and just buy 100 switches, choose the best 10, test those 10, and choose the best 1 from the 10. Unless you're going to manufacture these for others, making switches is a mechanical art, and likely to end in frustration for you unless you're already a Mechanical Engineer as well as an EE. The switch that "feels the best" to you should do the job.

Comment: If you don't like that answer then do the digital solution you hate, but dedicate a PIC or ATTiny, and make it so simple that it's obviously correct and you never have to worry about it again. That's actually the best solution for you.

Comment: Very good illustration of what you actually want, by the way!  Good job!

Comment: a microswitch has that kind of hysteresis

Comment: Digital pianos do this. One button that hits two contacts successively on the way down plus some logic or software. Otherwise messy mechanically.

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: Did you look for double-action switches that have a half-way and full-way switch like used as the trigger in cameras? This plus one or two logic gates would do the job, I guess.

Comment: #jsotola  has the right idea: a microswitch with a long actuating arm. The arm is at right angles to a spring return mechanical button. The button has a fixed travel distance, and the microswitch is adjusted to set the ON and OFF positions as needed. I have seen similar setups in the postal lock switch inside apartment intercoms.

Answer (score 5):

That's a mechanical hysteresis, and rather common for things like keyboard switches, usually also paired with a change in spring force that works as subconscious acknowledgement that the press has been registered.

It is usually difficult to gradually release these buttons, because at the point where the release is registered, the spring force also returns, and the button returns to "fully released" position immediately.

Having the switch point at the maximum travel distance is generally undesirable -- for an user actuated switch this would mean having to push against the endstop to get a reliable connection (which is very annoying), and for something like a position switch it would mean that the apparatus would need to stop instantly, limiting travel speed.

Answer (score 5):

Switches for cranes often have multiple levels, for example Schneider XENG1191, maybe that's something to look into.

Another option is to look into stackable panel switches. Often the breaking switch happens a few millimeters before the making switch. If you stack these, you can have simple logic engage only when both have had a transition.

Comment: The identifying feature in the XENG1191 seems to be the spring return NO_CL (33-34) contact.